# Как получить случайное число из диапазона?

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

суть программы в том,что пользователь вводит два числа,которые являются диапазоном.Из этого диапазона пользователь получает случайное значение. То же самое и с именем.Есть файл в 2000 строк(в каждой строке имя).Как сделать вывод рандомного имени?Всё ли у меня правильно?

```
print("твое случайное число : ")
print(random.randint(mini , maxi))

print("твое случайное имя : ")

with open("input.txt") as inp:
    lines = inp.readlines()

random_line = random.choice(lines).strip()
```

выдаёт ошибку в строке `print(random.randint(mini , maxi))`

ошибка выглядит так

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "nn.py", line 29, in
> <module>
>     lines = inp.readlines()   File "C:\Users\pavlv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py",
> line 23, in decode
>     return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position
> 13: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: суть программы в том,что пользователь вводит два числа,которые являются диапазоном.Из этого диапазона пользователь получает случайное значение.

То же самое и с именем.Есть файл в 2000 строк(в каждой строке имя).Как сделать вывод рандомного имени?Всё ли у меня правильно?

Comment: А судя по стектрейсу ошибка на строке `lines = inp.readlines()`, кому верить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При открытии файла, если не указывать кодировку, будет использоваться системная, а у вас это `windows-1252`, а в файле используется другая кодировка.

Попробуйте явно указывать `utf-8`:

```
...
with open("input.txt", encoding="utf-8") as inp:
    lines = inp.readlines()
...
```

Comment: Скорее системная win-1252. В кодировке win-1251 символ 0x8F существует - «Џ» (Заглавная сербская Джэ), а в 1252 - отсутствует. Но действительно этот символ вероятнее встретить в UTF-8, чем в 1251

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, вы правы, системная кодировка еще по файлу в трассе стека есть -- `cp1252.py` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

mini = int(input("Число от:"))
maximum = int(input("Число до: "))

print(random.randint(mini, maximum))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]